# Нужен скрипт для вывода всех игнорируемых файлов из .gitignore

Tags: git

Нужно отобразить все игнорируемые файлы как я понял.
Файлы в .gitignore добавил, нужен сам скрипт как я понял :\
Буду очень рад, если кто-то поможет!

Files to turn in : git_ignore.sh
Allowed functions : None
Notes : n/a

**• In this exercice, you will write a short shell script that lists all the existing files
ignored by your GiT repository. Example:**

%> bash git_ignore.sh | cat -e

.DS_Store$

mywork.c~$

%>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
while read LINE; do
     echo "Ignored: $LINE"
done < $FILE
```

Команда: `bash git_ignore.sh .gitignore`

---

Вариант 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
     echo "Ignored: $LINE"
done < .gitignore
```

Команда: `bash git_ignore.sh`

Comment: Так-то работает, спасибо) Но тут уточнили что условия именно этой задачи, чтоб по команде bash git_ignore.sh он выводил содержимое gitignore .

Тоесть bash git_ignore.sh (без этого .gitignore)

Comment: @BreadMan смотрите вариант 2

Comment: Благодарю, всё работает как надо!